# Can VirtualBox use unallocated space on hard drive for its virtual HD?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

This may be silly question for some more experienced guys. I have more than 100 GB of unallocated space on my hard drive. So I was thinking, that instead of using the space in my Ubuntu partition, it would be nice if the (virtual) hard drive for VirtualBox could be created in that unallocated space. Because once I have more than one or two OS-s installed in VirtualBox they occupy considerable amount of space in Ubuntu partition.

I have dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Win 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Unallocated space needs to be formatted first**. It would be safer to
  format it as NTFS since you have a dual boot setup. That way files
  would be accessible from both Windows and Ubuntu.
- **Transfer your existing VHD** or other virtual hard disk file **to that
  new partition** and load it into Virtualbox. (Link your virtual OS to the new location where you copied your VHD)
- Change the settings for your virtual OS in Virtualbox and increase it to the size you wish to allocate

*E.g.*

- My Ubuntu-1 VHD file is in partition A (Flexible allocation of 8GB)
- I format my unallocated space to NTFS and call it partition B
- I move my VHD file to B and update Ubuntu-1's storage settings to link it to its new location
- I increase allocation of the VHD to 250GB now

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A virtual hard drive is a file, so it needs to go in a partition that is formatted with a file system.  There's nothing stopping you from creating a partition for some or all of your unallocated space, formatting the partition, and then putting your virtual hard drive file or files there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only after you format the unallocated space.

In Windows 8.1, right-click on the Start button and select 'Disk Management'.  Once the snap-in loads, right-click on the unallocated partition, Select 'New Simple Volume' and follow the steps to choose the size of the partition, Volume name, Drive Letter, format, and other options.

In Ubuntu, gparted (a partition management tool) can be used to create the partition

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

A partition can then be created and formatted in the unallocated space.